# Amplitude of fermion decay with Majorana mass insertion

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, majorana-fermions

Consider the following Lagrangian,

$$ L \supset \frac{1}{2} m \overline{\psi}\psi^C + g \phi\, \overline{\chi}\,P_R\,\psi + \rm{h.c.} $$

where $\psi$ is a heavy fermion with a Majorana mass $m$, $\phi$ is a light scalar and $\chi$ is a light fermion.

$\psi$ can decay into a $\phi^\dagger \chi$ pair and the amplitude for this process is
$$i\mathcal{M} =  ig \, \overline{u}_\chi(p) P_R u_\psi(p)$$

But $\psi$ can also decay into the conjugate state $\phi \chi^C$ if we include a mass insertion (a cross) in the Feynman diagram. I'm expecting the decay rate for this process to be the same, but I don't know how to compute the amplitude for this 2nd decay channel.

I thought it was simply a matter of adding a fermion propagator $i (\not{p}+m)/(p^2-m^2)$ and keeping the mass term, but this changes the dimension of $\mathcal{M}$, so I must be doing something wrong. How does one deal with such a Majorana mass operator in a Feynman diagram? I know something similar happens in the seesaw mechanism, but I never really understood that either.